# Laravel 5.8 query from column containing json data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column that contains a json array, but I am having difficulty outputting them as individual items.

**ListingController@show**

```
public function show(Listing $listing)
{
    $services = collect($listing->services_offered);

    return view('listings.listing', compact('banner', 'listing', 'services'));
}
```

**listing.blade.php**

```
@foreach($services as $service)
    <li>{{$service}}</li>
@endforeach
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Try to cast type for your column: [see Laravel documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Listing` model you can cast the `json` array into a PHP array like this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'services_offered' => 'array',
];
```

Then you can wrap that into a collection as you already do and list them on the view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the JSON string to actual JSON array.

```
$services = collect(json_decode($listing->services_offered, true));
```

or you can create an accessor in your model

```
public function getServicesOfferedAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}
```